# Form sent to twice using mail()

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

i am totally new in php and websites. I have issue on my website with form if somebody can help me?

**Problem:** whenever the user presses the send button, the form is sent twice and two emails arrive in the inbox.
I assume something is triggering prigovor-submit.php twice but i can not find the reason.

**This is my prigovor-submit.php code:**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
// Validate the form data
$errors = [];

// Prigovor Type (Radio Buttons)
if (!isset($_POST["prigovorType"]) || empty($_POST["prigovorType"])) {
    $errors[] = "Please select a type.";
}

// Full Name
$fullName = $_POST["fullName"];
if (empty($fullName)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter your full name.";
} elseif (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/", $fullName)) {
    $errors[] = "Invalid characters in the full name.";
}

$oib = $_POST["oib"];

// Email
$email = $_POST["email"];
if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
}

// Message
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Accept Policy
if (!isset($_POST["acceptPolicy"])) {
    $errors[] = "Please accept the privacy policy.";
}

$brUgovora = $_POST["brUgovora"];
$postalCode = $_POST["postalCode"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$street = $_POST["street"];
$prigovorType = $_POST["prigovorType"];

if (empty($errors)) {
    $headers = "From: mail@mail.hr\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    $to = "to@mail.hr"; // Replace with your email address
    $subject = "[Prigovor - ". $prigovorType ."] " . $oib;        
    $messageWithBreaks = str_replace(["\r\n", "\r", "\n"], '<br>', mb_convert_encoding($_POST["message"], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $body = "<strong>Ime i prezime:</strong> $fullName<br>";
    $body .= "<strong>Email:</strong> $email<br>";
    $body .= "<strong>Broj predmet:</strong> $brUgovora<br>";
    $body .= "<strong>Tekst prigovora:</strong><br>$messageWithBreaks<br><br>";
    if (!empty($street) && !empty($postalCode) && !empty($city)) {
        $body .= "<strong>________________________________________________________________________________</strong><br>";
        $body .= "<strong>Adresa za dostavu odgovora:</strong> $street, $postalCode $city<br>";
        $body .= "<strong>________________________________________________________________________________</strong>";
    }
    // Send email
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $email)) {
        // Email sent successfully
        echo json_encode(["status" => "success"]);
    } else {
        // Email sending failed
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Failed to send email"]);

    }

    // Optionally, you can redirect the user to a thank you page
    // header("Location: thank-you.html");

    exit();
} else {
    // If there are errors, you might want to handle them appropriately.
    // For now, let's assume you want to output them as JSON.
    echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "errors" => $errors]);
    exit();
}
}

?>
```

**This is my html:**

```
        <div class="prigovor-container">
        <div class="popup-container" id="popupContainer">
            <div class="popup-box">
                <h1>Pozdrav!</h1>
                <p>Prigovor uspješno poslan!</p>
                <button class="close-btn" id="closeBtn">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="myForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate action="prigovor-submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Checkboxes -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Vrsta otkupljenog potraživanja:*</label><br>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="radio3" name="prigovorType" value="Neprihodonosni kredit" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio3">Neprihodonosni kredit</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="radio4" name="prigovorType" value="Ostala potraživanja" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio4">Ostala potraživanja</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Full Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fullName">Puno ime:*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" placeholder="Unesite ime i prezime" required name="fullName">
        </div>

        <!-- OIB -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="oib">OIB:*</label>
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oib" placeholder="Unesite Vaš OIB" required name="oib"> -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oib" placeholder="Unesite Vaš OIB (maksimalno 11 znamenki)" maxlength="11" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Unesite samo brojeve" required name="oib">

        </div>

        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Adresa e-pošte:*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Unesite adresu e-pošte" required name="email">
        </div>

        <!-- Broj ugovora -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="brUgovora">Broj predmeta/ugovora:</label>
            <input type="brUgovora" class="form-control" id="brUgovora" placeholder="Unesite broj predmeta/ugovora" name="brUgovora">
        </div>

        <!-- Message Box -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Vaš prigovor napišite ovdje:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Unesite poruku" name="message" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Želim dostavu odgovora:*</label><br>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="radio1" name="deliveryPreference" value="option1" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">putem e-pošte</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="radio2" name="deliveryPreference" value="option2" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">na adresu stanovanja</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="address" style="display:none;">
            <label for="address">Adresa stanovanja:*</label>
            <div class="address-cont">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalCode" placeholder="Poštanski broj" name="postalCode">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Grad" name="city">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" placeholder="Ulica i kućni broj" name="street">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- File Attachment 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="attachment">Attachment (Accepted types: .doc, .docx, .pdf, .jpeg, .jpg, .png)</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="attachment" name="attachment">
        </div>-->

        <!-- Accept Policy -->
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="acceptPolicy" required name="acceptPolicy">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="acceptPolicy">Pročitao/pročitala sam i <a href="https://website.com/pravila-privatnosti.php" target="_blank" tabindex="0">prihvaćam politiku privatnosti</a>.*</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <!--<button type="submit" class="show-popup">Submit</button>-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn submit" id="submitBtn">Pošalji</button>
        
        </form>
    </div>


 <script src="form-validation.js" defer></script>
 <script src="popupscript.js"></script>
```

**And this is my popupscript.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const popupContainer = document.querySelector('.popup-container');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');

// Function to show the popup
function showPopup() {
    popupContainer.classList.add('active');
}

// Function to close the popup
function closePopup() {
    popupContainer.classList.remove('active');
}

// Close button click event
closeBtn.onclick = closePopup;

// Form submit event
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

    // Fetch data from the form
    const formData = new FormData(this);

    // Make an AJAX request to prigovor-submit.php
    fetch('prigovor-submit.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Check if the form submission was successful
        if (data.status === 'success') {
            // Display the popup
            showPopup();
        } else {
            // Handle errors if needed
            console.error('Form submission failed:', data.message);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
});
```

**Code from form-validation.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

    form.classList.add('was-validated');
});

// Additional custom validation logic can be added here
   });


const radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1');
const radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
const addressDiv = document.getElementById('address');
const addressInput = document.getElementById('address');
const postalInput = document.getElementById('postalCode');
const cityInput = document.getElementById('city');
const streetInput = document.getElementById('street');

// Add an event listener to the radio buttons
radio1.addEventListener('change', toggleAddress);
radio2.addEventListener('change', toggleAddress);

// Function to toggle the visibility and required status of additionalInfo div
function toggleAddress() {
    addressDiv.style.display = radio2.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    addressInput.required = radio2.checked;
    postalInput.required = radio2.checked;
    cityInput.required = radio2.checked;
    streetInput.required = radio2.checked;
}
```

Comment: Testing here, https://jsfiddle.net/pdmx4srz/, I can see only one single request after clicking the submit button. Check what happens on your actual site, by looking at the requests in the browser dev tools network panel. `form-validation.js` - we have not seen what that script does, maybe it interferes somehow.

Comment: Agreed, first task is to use the network inspector and js debugger to analyse this. Also check the webserver logs for requests to the php scripts and look at timings, client IPs etc to analyse patterns

Comment: Topic edited, i included form-validation.js

Comment: You seem to have two entirely separate "submit" handlers - one which does validation, and one which tries to send the data via AJAX. But the AJAX one doesn't wait for validation to complete, it just sends anyway. So that might not be helping, and it certainly doesn't make any logical sense. Did you check the Network tool yet in the browser? Watch it while you're using your page, and submitting the form. What have you observed? (Remember to use the "preserve log" setting so you can see results even if the page then gets refreshed for any reason)

Comment: The validation function should use `stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent the second event listener from running.

Comment: I found on another place defined "<script src="popupscript.js"></script> ".  After removing it, script was triggered only once. Obviously it helped, but does it really work like that (how many times it is defined, so many times it will trigger)?

Comment: @ADyson thank you for pointing out the two separate "submit" handlers, I rewrote the code to have only one handler

Comment: Yes, because it would add another "submit" event listener to the page. An event can have an infinite number of listeners assigned to it, and they will all trigger when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script below was called twice on different lines and that caused double trigger.

```
<script src="popupscript.js"></script>
```